Trying to write query to provide rows for All Fields
I've been trying to write a query in Google Sheets to take the harvest results from the two upper tables and generate the lower table. I'm not sure how to combine them so that no fruits are missing in the final report. Thanks in advance.

I tried to combine the rows, but I keep getting duplicates

You may try QUERY() function pivot clause.
=QUERY(HSTACK(SCAN("",A:A,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x))),B:C),
"select Col2, sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")



thanks. This is simple and quite elegant - it worked well. I still have a few modifications, but I'm still having a few challenges in other aspects of a complete report. Could I ask some additional questions directly to complete my task - which is to track revenue and expenses among several friends?

First, if this helps your current question then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it as green) to treat the current thread is solved. Then you can ask question. If the question is different then it is advised to ask a separate question here on stack-overflow.

You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
   u,UNIQUE({B2:B3;B6:B7}),
   IFNA(VSTACK(
     HSTACK(,"West","North"),
     HSTACK(u,VLOOKUP(u,B2:C3,2,0),VLOOKUP(u,B6:C8,2,0))))))


This is very close. I gave two simple tables. If the two source tables have a different number of rows, then blank lines are inserted. Also, I would like all the rows sorted by the fruit in ascending order. I would assume a "IS NOT NULL" would need to be included. And, somewhere, the resulting table needs to be sorted in ascending order.

can you share a sample sheet that's representative of your data?
